# Maxscript trying to change material id of each object

Tags: maxscript

I am using 3D Max Design which is odd with material ids.
I am trying to revert all objects with name starting with Prism back to an id number of 10. I thought this would have been a bit straight forward however I am really new at Maxscript. My current code is such.

```
    myObjects = $'Prim-5m*' as array

     for i = 11 to myObjects.count do
       (
myobjects[i].modifiers[#VspMatMod].materialID=10
        )
```

I am not sure if I have to pass? I really don't understand how this works. The VsmMatMod is the modifier for the material channel of this object. If I was to convert the box to add a modifier of material would this work better?
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sorted. I found another one liner for something else and modified it
My resultant is;

```
        MyObjects = $'Pri*' as array

    for obj in myObjects do obj.modifiers[#VspMatMod].materialID = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use

```
for node in $Prism* where (modi = node.modifiers[#VspMatMod]) != undefined do  modi.materialID = 10
```